# Query to Display records except Initial Record

Tags: mysql

For my project, i have a requirement where i have to display all the records in descending order except the first record. I am kind of messed up. Anyways, i have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ins_nr nl WHERE nl.nl_status = '2' ORDER BY nl.nl_id DESC
```

Here, i have a table called `ins_nr` which will display all the records with `status` 2 and the `id` which is the primary key(unique). It is displaying in `desc` order perfectly.

I dont want the first record from the top alone. What should i do? How to modify the above query..?

Comment: How should the first record get sorted then?

Comment: OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1 QUADRILLION

Comment: @DarshanMehta, i do not know, the latest record / the first record is not needed for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use OFFSET. Then you can skip 1 records and select the remaining ones until the end.
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM ins_nr nl WHERE nl.nl_status = '2'
         ORDER BY nl.nl_id DESC LIMIT 99999999999 OFFSET 1;
```

> OR ( You could also use a shorter syntax to achieve the same result: )

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1, 999999999";
```

Comment: For the above query, how to omit the last one by giving `OFFSET`

Comment: @Keynes .. You try this ?

Comment: @Keynes .. For Reference Read This :  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: yes boss, it worked. Is it a good question, no one up voted me, but i searched quiet a long time in stack overflow and not found

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `offset` clause.  This looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM ins_nr nl
WHERE nl.nl_status = '2'
ORDER BY nl.nl_id DESC
LIMIT 999999999 OFFET 1;
```

Unfortunately, `LIMIT` is required.  For this situation, it is traditional to just put in a very large number.

Also, if `nl_status` is numeric, then use `nl.nl_status = 2`.  Don't compare strings to numbers.

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 1

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dynamic rownum and filter on it to omit the first row, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT nl.*, @r := @r + 1 AS `rn`
    FROM ins_nr nl, (SELECT @r := 0) 
    WHERE nl.nl_status = '2' 
    ORDER BY nl.nl_id DESC
) a 
WHERE a.rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to get the max id from subquery and put it in a where clausole